# How to display Rows based on number of Days (From Dates) in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, timedelta

I have a Dataframe which looks like below after some coding. Now, I want to display only those rows where "Name" is repeating 3 or more days.

Sample Data Frame:

[image: Sample Data Frame]

The Output required is:

[image: Required Output]

Comment: Your question must have been downvoted because you posted images. That is not recommended.

Comment: Images posted because i am working on Excel files automation with python. Secondly, a newbie, will try not to put images next time rather than codes which i tried.

Comment: I didnt down vote. Was just advice. You can always copy dataframe as follows. `df.to_json(orient='records')`. If a huge dataframe, go send `df.head` to json.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome u2k to Stackoverflow.

You could try:

```
name_count = df.Name.value_counts()
df[df.Name.isin(name_count.index[name_count.gt(2)])]
```

---

**Output:**

```
    Name    Account
0   Ryan    1
1   Ryan    2
2   Ryan    3
3   Ryan    4
```

---

Dataset I've created looks like:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Name":["Ryan", "Ryan", "Ryan", "Ryan", "David", "David", "Peter"],
    "Account":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
})

    Name    Account
0   Ryan    1
1   Ryan    2
2   Ryan    3
3   Ryan    4
4   David   5
5   David   6
6   Peter   7
```